# Redux - Passing reducer an action seems to have undefined id

Tags: redux, react-redux

I did the [basic redux todolist tutorial](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) and it worked but I wanted to get to know the code by making a small change.

I changed:

**actions/index.js**

```
let nextTodoId = 0
export const addTodo = (text) => {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    id: nextTodoId++,
    text
  }
}
```

to this:

```
let nextTodoId = 0
export const addTodo = (text) => {
   return {
      type: 'ADD_TODO',
      payload: {
         id: nextTodoId++,
         text: text
      }
   }
}
```

And I got the adding a todo working with that but a strange side effect has occurred in the toggleTodo - There are no console errors but clicking a todo list item is supposed to toggle it between being completed (visually has a strike through the text) and being not completed. Clicking a list item now has no effect.

I'm struggling to pass this reducer an action which has a defined `id`.

**reducers/todos.js:**

[image]

This is the code which calls the `toggleTodo(id)` reducer (look for the arrow pointing and saying "HERE"):

**containers/visibleTodoList.js:**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { toggleTodo } from '../actions'
import TodoList from '../components/TodoList'

const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
  switch (filter) {
    case 'SHOW_ALL':
      return todos
    case 'SHOW_COMPLETED':
      return todos.filter(t => t.completed)
    case 'SHOW_ACTIVE':
      return todos.filter(t => !t.completed)
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    todos: getVisibleTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter)
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onTodoClick: (id) => {
      dispatch(toggleTodo(id)) <-------------HERE
    }
  }
}

const VisibleTodoList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList)

export default VisibleTodoList
```

So the id is coming from `onTodoClick`.

**components/TodoList.js:**

[image]

So I pause it there and see the value of `onTodoClick()`:

[image]

Where in the [original code](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) was it setting `onTodoClick.id` so I can repeat it again to get the `onTodoClick.id` to be defined (thus hopefully causing the clicking a todo item to toggle successfully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `state.id !== action.id` but you pass it as `action.payload.id` do the following:

```
case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
 if (state.id !== action.payload.id) {
  return state
 }
```

Comment: yep, because the id property was relocated